# I import video successfully and davinci able to locate file but video not playing why?

Tags: video-editor, davinci-resolve

[image: davinci resolve media menu]

I import video successfully and davinci  able to locate file but video not playing why ?**strong text**

Comment: Try the beginners tutorial: Open the inspector or metadata to see properties of the file. "MP4" is just a container format.